# Как связать 2 таблицы один ко многим в моем скрипте?

Tags: php, mysql, ооп, order

```
$DB = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname={$table}", $user, $pass);

class SQl
{
    public static function initDataBase ()
    {
        $createProducts =
            /** @lang text */
            "CREATE TABLE products (  
              products_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
              products_name VARCHAR(30),
              products_description VARCHAR(30),
              products_price INT NOT NULL,
              status VARCHAR(30) -- NOT NULL UNIQUE
        )";

        $createClients =
            /** @lang text */
            "CREATE TABLE clients (  
              clients_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
              clients_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
              clients_mesagge VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
              clients_phone INT NOT NULL
        )";

        $createOrders =
            /** @lang text */
            "CREATE TABLE orders (
              client_id   INT NOT NULL,    
              products_id INT NOT NULL, 
              ??????????
        )";

        global $DB;
        $DB->prepare( $createProducts )->execute();
        $DB->prepare( $createClients  )->execute();
        $DB->prepare( $createOrders   )->execute();

    }
}

SQl::initDataBase();
```

то-есть один клиент может заказать много товаров

Comment: И значит в `orders` будет много записей. Проблема в чем?

Comment: не могу нагуглить синтаксис sql, как дописать $createOrders

Comment: А что туда надо дописать?

Comment: это я и спрашиваю в этом вопросе )

Comment: что-то типа FOREIGN KEY (client_id) REFERENCES client (client_id)

Answer (score -2):

Клиенты и продукты никак не связаны.

Связаны между собой заказ-продукты и заказ-клиент. Вот исходя их этого:

таблица заказов:

```
id_заказа | id_клиента | еще поля
```

таблица продуктов в заказе:

```
id_заказа | id_продукта
```